# Footer is getting overlapped with content in XSLT

Tags: html, css, xml, xslt, xsd

[In the image we can see the footer got overlapped with the content](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MVaWV.png)    I have a xsl and want the footer on every page of it. What is happening is my content and footer is getting overlapped.  Is there any way in xsl to prevent this??

I have a footer at the bottom of the xsl and the content of this footer is getting overlapped with the other page content. I have tried all ways to make it correct but it is not working. Please suggest is there any way to do it.

If I am changing the position from fixed to absolute or relative of footer, then footer gets displayed only on the last page.
I want the footer on all the pages.

This is the xsl here.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="3.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:sch="http://services.equifax.com/eport/ws/schemas/1.0">
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <html>
            
                <head>
                <style type="text/css">
   table { page-break-inside:avoid }
    tr    { page-break-inside:avoid; page-break-after:auto }
    td    { page-break-inside:avoid; page-break-after:auto }
    thead { display:table-header-group }
    tfoot { display:table-footer-group }
    @media print {
    .pagebreak { page-break-before: always; }
    
    } 
    footer {  text-align: center;
                 font-size: 0.3cm;
                 width: 100%;
                 position: running(pageFooter);
                 size:landscape;
                 color: #f00;
                 bottom: 0;
                 margin-top:1cm; 
                 position:fixed;
                 height:4%;
                
              }
}

@page {
  @bottom-right {
    content: counter(page);
  }
}

    
       </style>

            </head>
            
            <body style="margin:0cm 0.5cm 0cm 1cm;">
                <p></p>
                
                
<table width="100%">
    <tbody >
        <tr>
             <td>
                <p>
                    <strong>
                         Our Ref: EBKL/HQ/
                         <xsl:value-of select="NG_EQ_COMPOSITE_OFFER_PROC/WFINSTRUMENTTABLE/ASSIGNEDUSER"/>
                    </strong>
                    <strong>
                         /<xsl:value-of select="NG_EQ_COMPOSITE_OFFER_PROC/NG_EQ_PROPOSAL_DETAILS/SOL_ID"/>
                    </strong>
                    <strong>
                         /
                    </strong>
                     <xsl:value-of select="NG_EQ_COMPOSITE_OFFER_PROC/WI_NAME_TIMESTAMP/WI_NAME"/>
                </p>
                
                <p>
                    <xsl:value-of select="NG_EQ_COMPOSITE_OFFER_PROC/WI_NAME_TIMESTAMP/TIMESTAMP"/>
                </p>
                
                <p>
        
            

            </p>    
            
            
            
                                
            
                
                <p>
                    Dear Sir/ Madam,
                </p>
                
                <p>
                    <u>
                        <strong>
                             RE: *********ING FACILITY
                        </strong>
                    </u>
                </p>
                
                <p>
                    ********* ********* (*********) Limited (the *********) is pleased to offer you the Facility set out below (the Facility) on the following terms and conditions:
                </p>
                
                    
                            <p >
                                1.1. "*********" means ********* ********* (*********) Limited whose address is care of Post Office Box Number 75104-00200 Nairobi and includes its successors and assigns (whether immediate or derivative).
                            </p>
                        
                            <p >
                                1.2. "Borrower" means
                                <strong>
                                 <xsl:if test="NG_EQ_COMPOSITE_OFFER_PROC/NG_EQ_BORROWER_DETAILS/BORROWER_ENTITY_TYPE='Non-Individual'">
                                    <xsl:value-of select="NG_EQ_COMPOSITE_OFFER_PROC/NG_EQ_BORROWER_DETAILS/ENTITY_NAME"/>&#160;
                                      <xsl:value-of select="NG_EQ_COMPOSITE_OFFER_PROC/NG_EQ_OFFER_LETTER_HEADER/REGISTERED_NAME"/>
                                 </xsl:if>
                                  <xsl:if test="NG_EQ_COMPOSITE_OFFER_PROC/NG_EQ_BORROWER_DETAILS/BORROWER_ENTITY_TYPE='Individual'">
                                    <xsl:value-of select="NG_EQ_COMPOSITE_OFFER_PROC/NG_EQ_BORROWER_DETAILS/APPLICANT_NAME"/>
                                <xsl:for-each select="//NG_EQ_COMPOSITE_OFFER_PROC/NG_EQ_CO_BORROWER">
                                    <xsl:if test="CO_BORROWER_NAME  !=''">, <xsl:value-of select="CO_BORROWER_NAME"/>   </xsl:if>
                                </xsl:for-each>
                                   </xsl:if>
                                </strong>
                                 whose address is care of
                                <strong>
                <xsl:for-each select="//NG_EQ_COMPOSITE_OFFER_PROC/NG_EQ_ADDRESS_DETAILS">
                    <span> <xsl:value-of select="ADDRESS_LINE_1"/> - <xsl:value-of select="POSTAL_CODE"/></span>,
                    <xsl:if test="ADDRESS_LINE_2 !=''"><span  > <xsl:value-of select="ADDRESS_LINE_2"/> </span>,</xsl:if>
                    <xsl:if test="ADDRESS_LINE_3 !=''">   <span  > <xsl:value-of select="ADDRESS_LINE_3"/> </span>,</xsl:if>
                    <xsl:if test="LANDMARK !=''">    <span > <xsl:value-of select="LANDMARK"/> </span>,</xsl:if>
                    <span> <xsl:value-of select="TOWN"/> </span>,
                    <span> <strong> <xsl:value-of select="COUNTRY"/> </strong> </span>
                </xsl:for-each> 
                                </strong>
                                 and shall include its successors in title.
                            </p>
                        
                            <p >
                                1.3. "Interest Rate" means the *********’s lending interest rate for the currency or currencies in which the Facility is advanced or outstanding and is the rate of interest that the ********* shall at its sole discretion from time to time charge within the limits permitted by law.
                            </p>
                        
                            <p >
                                1.4. "CBR" means the publicly quoted Reference Rate stipulated by the Monetary Policy Committee of the Central ********* of ********* (CBK), subject to change from time to time (currently <xsl:value-of select="NG_EQ_COMPOSITE_OFFER_PROC/NG_EQ_OFFER_LETTER_DETAILS/CENTRAL_*********_RATE"/>% per annum). In the event that the Central ********* of ********* ceases to have a CBR, CBR shall mean the rate of interest that the ********* shall at its sole discretion from time to time charge within the limits permitted by law.
                            </p>
                        
                            <p >
                                1.5. "Margin" means an interest calculated by the ********* after taking into account the following:
                            </p>    
    
            <p>
            (i) The *********’s costs, benefits and risk of funds (deposit) during the tenure of the Loan.
            </p>
        
            <p >
            (ii) The *********’s required net income return as a percentage of shareholders’ ********* multiplied by the minimum regulatory required capital.
            </p>
        
            <p >
            (iii) Credit risk premium being factors that affect a customer, business or industry/sector’s ability to repay the Loan; and
            </p>
        
            <p >
            (iv)    The *********’s operational costs associated with originating the Loan.
            </p>
        


                            
                        
                            <p >
                                1.6. "Business Day" means a day other than a Sunday or gazetted public holiday on which *********s are open for business in *********;
                            </p>
                        
                            <p >
                                1.7. "Facility" means the Facility made available pursuant to this Letter details of which are set out in Sections A1 and A2 of this Letter.
                            </p>
                        
                            <p >
                                1.8. "Event of Default" means any one of the events specified in Paragraph 5 of this Letter.
                            </p>
                        
                            <p >
                                1.9. "Encumbrance" includes any mortgage, charge (whether fixed or floating), pledges, lien, hypothecation, assignment by way of security, security interest, title retention, trust arrangement, preferential rights of set-off, counterclaim, *********er’s lien or other encumbrance whatsoever securing any obligation of any person and/or conferring a priority of payment in respect of any obligation of any person;
                            </p>
                        
                            <p >
                                1.10. "Kes" means ********* Shillings - the lawful currency of the Republic of *********
                            </p>
                        
                            <p >
                                1.11. "Letter" means this Facility Letter and the accompanying annexures hereto.
                            </p>
                        
                            <p >
                                1.12. "Security" means the security details of which are set out in Section A3 to this Letter and/or any security created or to be created by the Borrower or at the request of the Borrower by any third party in favour of the ********* to secure repayment of the Facility;
                            </p>
                        
                            <p >
                                1.13. The headings in this Letter are inserted for convenience only and shall be ignored in construing this Letter.
                            </p>
                        
                            <p >
                                1.14. The word "Person" shall include a natural person, firm, company, corporation, trust, unincorporated body of persons or any state or government or any agency thereof.
                            </p>
                        
                            <p >
                                1.15. References to any agreement, document or instrument (including this Letter) means, such agreement, document or instrument (including this letter) as is supplemented, amended or varied from time to time between the parties thereto in accordance with the terms (if applicable) hereof and thereof.
                            </p>
                        
                
                            
                    
                
                <p>
                    <u>
                        <strong>
                             SECTION B
                        </strong>
                    </u>
                </p>
                
                
                <p>
                    <strong>
                         1. INTEREST:
                    </strong>
                </p>
                  
                <p >
                    1.1 The Borrower shall pay interest as well after as before any demand judgement *********ruptcy or liquidation (as the case may be). Interest (whether normal interest or default interest) shall accrue from day to day, will be calculated on cleared balances inclusive of the first and last days of the period during which it accrues on the basis of the actual number of days elapsed on a 365-day year, will be debited to the Borrower’s account with the ********* in accordance with the usual mode of the ********* monthly in arrears and will be compounded in the event of not being punctually paid.
                </p>
                  
                <p>
                    1.2 The ********* may from time to time revise the rate of interest chargeable upon giving 30 days’ notice to the Borrower and the statement of the ********* as to the rate or amount of interest payable at any one time shall in the absence of manifest error be conclusive.
                </p>
                
                <p>
                    1.3 If any sum payable by the Borrower is not paid on the date on which it is due in accordance with the provisions of this Letter or under any judgment of any Court the Borrower shall pay default interest on such sum in addition to normal interest. The Borrower agrees that the rate of default interest specified in Section A of this letter represents a reasonable pre-estimate of the loss to be suffered by the ********* in funding and administering the default of the Borrower.
                </p>
                
                
                <p>
                    <strong>
                         2. FEES:
                    </strong>
                </p>
                
                <p>
                    2.1 In addition to the fees set out in Section A of this letter, the Borrower will pay to the ********* such other fees and charges according to the *********’s tariff from time to time.
                </p>
                
                
                <p>
                    <strong>
                         3. SECURITY:
                    </strong>
                </p>

  
  
  
  
    </td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

```
        **<footer align="center">
                    READ AND ACCEPTED <br/>
                    SIGN……………………….………………
        </footer>** 

</body>
        </html>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>



Thanks in advance
```

Comment: yes. add your markup + styles to fix.

Comment: Yes I have added it. Kindly suggest

Comment: seriously? your css units are in `cm`? your css has so many errors...